# Column sorting in data-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, handsontable

I have a data-grid (jquery.handsontable) that's filled by users information.

```
 var tableInstance = table.handsontable('getInstance');
 data = DataHelper.Users.getData();
 fillTable(data);
```

I need to sort this table by columns. In this lib option is already implemented for this.

```
table.handsontable({
  ...                
    columnSorting : true,
  ...        
  });
```

When I click on the column-header it sorts a data only in view-layer and don't sort it in collection ( data = DataHelper.Users.getData();)

P.S. Sorry for my English -- it's not my native language.

Comment: Since your English is not your native language, can you help me understand with a data sample.  For example show partial table of your result then show the data of what you want the result to be. make sense?

Comment: @userDEV, Thanks for response ! I'm already solved this problem by using physical and logical indices.